# Access matched child route custom props (React Router v5)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

How could I access a matched route custom props from a parent Component in React?

That is, having a router like this (`react-router-config` style):

```
{
    component: App,
    routes: [
      {
        path: '/',
        exact: true,
        component: Home,
      },
      {
        path: '/account/',
        component: Account,
        headerOpened: true,
        routes: [
          {
            path: '/account/mi-cuenta/',
            exact: true,
            component: MyAccount,
          },
          {
            path: '/account/preferencias/',
            exact: true,
            component: Settings,
          },
          {
            path: '/account/mi-consumo/',
            exact: true,
            component: MyConsumption,
          },
        ],
      },
      { component: NotFound },
    ],
  }
```

How can I access from my `App` component the `headerOpened` custom prop being passed to `Account`?

Using the `withRouter` HOC in `App`, I'm unable to find anything inside the match or location object. The only thing I have is the location.pathname that shows, for example, `/account/mi-cuenta/`.

Then, I have the match object which only contains params (empty in this case) inside, but no sign of the `headerOpened` prop.

The reason to get this property from a parent component is that this one is the renderer of a `Header` component that needs to now about that value.

Here, a little snippet of what `App` component could look like:

```
return (
        <div>
          <Header opened={ ??? }/>
          {renderRoutes(route.routes)}
          <Footer />
        <div/>
    );
```

Comment: This, in my opinion, is a huge problem with the latest versions of react-router. How can I keep my components hierarchy making sense if there is no way to have a route-aware environment of props that I can access wherever I need to?

Comment: Its better to write more information about your code, i think for better understand your question, there is need to write `renderRoutes` function

Comment: Here you can see where `renderRoutes` function comes from https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-config